# dynamic css circle inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have repeatedly search the forum and google - tried all sorts of different things but I can't get it done...

I am trying to have a code a page with a fixed header and footer which has a centered circle in middle that changes size dynamically and does not overflow into either header or footer.

Please have a look at my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/p90pq8b3/3/

I am quite new so all of this but frankly I am a bit surprised why

```
 document.getElementById('circle').style.height = document.getElementById ('circle').style.width;
```

seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:
css:

```
#circle{
  position: absolute;
}
```

js:

```
   var w = $('#circle').width();
function f() {
 $('#circle').height($('#circle').width());
  if ($('#circle').height() > $('.wrapper').height()) {
    $('#circle').height($('.wrapper').height());
    $('#circle').width($('.wrapper').height());
  } else if ($('#circle').height() < w) {
    $('#circle').width($('.wrapper').height());

  }
  if ($('#circle').width() > $('.wrapper').width()) {
    $('#circle').width($('.wrapper').width());
  }
  }
f();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
f()
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uyt9z1qp/4/

Comment: Hi thx that worked ! no I just have to solve the problem of the circle element not drawing into the space of the header / footer. but thank you!!

Comment: It's probably just `position: absolute` instead of `relative`.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal where do you mean?

Comment: @madalinivascu You can check the jsfiddle in my answer. The circle is centered there.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal better check my jsfiddle don't know what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

This won't return the width

```
document.getElementById('circle').style.width
```

But this will (without `px`)

```
document.getElementById('circle').offsetWidth
```

Replace your `resize` function with this and it should work

```
function resize() {
  var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
      w = circle.offsetWidth;

  circle.style.height = w + 'px';
}
```

Here is an example on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/csxuhrjm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: Have you thought about actually using a real circle? You can embed *SVGs* in html. The actual size calculation for positioning remains.

```html
<svg height="200" width="200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green" />
    <text x="40" y="80" stroke="black">I am a circle!</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: the svg solution doesnt really make sense for me because I want the whole thing to be very dynamic but thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone thank you for helping to @madalin ivascu and his jquery solution.

I tweeked it a little so that i now have to navigational arrows and a truly responsive solution. If anyone is interested check it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/sd34j5k6/

```
if($('.wrapper').height() > $('.wrapper').width()) 
{
    $('#circle').width($ ('.wrapper').width() *0.7);
    $('#circle').height($('.wrapper').width() *0.7 );
}else if( $('.wrapper').width()  >  $('.wrapper').height() )
{
    $('#circle').width($('.wrapper').height() *0.9);
    $('#circle').height($('.wrapper').height() *0.9 );
}
```