# dynamic css circle navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question is a follow-up question (not sure if thats allowed) on something I asked earlier -> [dynamic css circle inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307941/dynamic-css-circle-inside-div)

The solution to that thread turned out not be what I wanted to achieve since I need the divs adjacent to the centered circle to be independent of it in order not to be affected by styles such as opacity i want to apply to the circle.

What I want to create is a page in which I have a fixed header and footer and a circle in the content area that dynamically changes size depending on the space available - i dont want to user to scroll.

Abovementioned circle has a div (the navigational part) on either side that will also change size.

The code that I have so far seems to work as expected when the x-axis of the wrapper is bigger than the y-axis (width > height) but for some reason when the height of the wrapper is bigger than width, it gets all distorted.

https://jsfiddle.net/h1xfqwh6/

looking at in in fiddle it actually looks half decent - besides the hidious colors - which are a feature... but if i look at in the firefox responsive design developer mode the circle takes always more space than it should when the wrapper containers height is larger than its width -

[oversized circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTH7L.png)

html

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
            <div id="circle">
                    <p> Make me into a real circle </p>
             </div>
        <div id="right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
     </div>
```

css

```
 .wrapper {
 top: 4em;
 bottom: 4em; 
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 max-height: 100%;
background-color: blue;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 1em;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}



#left{
background:#00ffff;
height: 100%;
border: 1px black solid;
display: inline-block;
}

#right{
background:#00ff03;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
float: right;
text-align: right;
border: 1px black solid;

}

#circle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 5em;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
 width: 50%; 
 background-color: green;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlIL8.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 border: black 2px solid; 
 }
```

jquery

```
function f() 
{


if($('.wrapper').height() > $('.wrapper').width()) 
{
    $('#circle').height($('.wrapper').width() - $('#left').width() - $('#right').width());      
    $('#circle').width($ ('.wrapper').height() - $('#left').width() - $('#right').width());
    $('.wrapper').width($('#circle').width() + $('#left').width() + $('#right').width()); 


}
else if( $('.wrapper').width()  >  $('.wrapper').height() )
{
    $('.wrapper').width($('#circle').width() + $('#left').width() + $('#right').width());
    $('#circle').width($('.wrapper').height() );
    $('#circle').height($('.wrapper').height() );

}
$('#circle').height($('#circle').width());

}
f();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
f();
});
```

Comment: Just so I understand what you are asking....You want a circle perfectly centered with a header and footer and the circle should not overlap the header and footer?  If this is the case, you really do not need any javascript for that...You can use `media queries` to resize your circle based on different screen sizes.

Comment: No, forget the header and the footer - they are fixed; and wont move. the problem is the navigation next to it